# What is a better way to earn reputation on Stack Exchange: Asking Questions or Answering questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

What is a better way to earn reputation on Stack Exchange network:

- Asking Questions?
- Answering Questions?

Comment: The best way is to participate positively on the sites by providing quality content and don't bother about reputation at all. It shouldn't be a goal by itself.

Comment: @rene That's an answer I'd upvote. Apparently, answering questions with answers instead of in the comments is a good way, too :P

Comment: @Vincent: on that point, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298901/what-to-do-if-user-always-uses-comments-for-correct-answers/

Comment: @rene Would upvote that answer, too. There's also this gem from years of old: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast/17250#17250

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I got the answer in "focus on constructive contribution and everything else will follow".

Answer (score 4):

Upvotes to answers give you twice as much reputation (+10) as upvotes to questions (+5)<sup>[1]</sup>. Also, answers tend to be upvoted more often.<sup>[2]</sup>

That would put the verdict in favour of answers, *but* these need a lot more expertise (or Google skills) than questions. It's easier to write a question about a subject you don't know much about than an answer. (In some cases, it becomes *harder* to write a good question if you know more about a subject, but I digress.)

Another point of view to this question is to look at it from the *site's* perspective. Check this [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered); sites like [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) have almost all their questions answered; they are mostly interested in (good) new questions. Sites like [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) on the other hand 'need' more (good) answers.

Some people have a natural talent for writing great questions, even as newcomers to a certain site/subject. It's hard to give a definitive answer to this question which holds for everybody. I think [@rene's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299436/which-is-better-way-to-earn-reputations-on-stack-exchange-asking-questions-or-a#comment973350_299436) is the bottom line: if you're enthusiastic about a subject, the reputation will follow.

<sub>[1]: except Stack Apps, where [upvotes to questions give +10 reputation](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-reputation) as well</sub>
<sub>[2]: this is true for most sites, e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708035/total-and-average-number-of-votes-per-question-and-answer), but not for some, e.g. [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/708035/total-and-average-number-of-votes-per-question-and-answer).</sub>

Comment: citation: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508)

Answer (score 2):

That's the wrong way to view reputation.

Reputation is a by-product of contributing positively to the Stack Exchange sites and in doing that your level of expertise will increase - that's certainly what has happened to me. And that is an example of a positive feedback loop.

Indeed an upvote on an answer you make is worth +10, and acceptance of an answer is +15. Compare that to a question upvote of +5. But the level of expertise necessary for an answer is beyond that for a question, although that said, only ask a question if you've researched a topic thoroughly.

Making edit suggestions is also a good way to become acquainted with the standards expected on the Stack Exchange sites, although, for what its worth, you only earn +2 per accepted edit if your overall reputation is less than 2,000.

All done and dusted, focus on contribution, not reputation.

Comment: rep is a measure of *trust*, not of *expertise*.  Me earning more rep doesn't make me more of an expert, it just means SE trusts me more than it did before.

Comment: That's not what it's designed to represent, and it's not something that it actually correlates to particularly strongly.  It's a measure of the *quantity* of the positive contributions a user has made to the site more so than the *quality* of the content provided, or the difficult or expertise required to post the contributions they've provided.

Answer (score 1):

From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you
>   
> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions
>   and useful answers. Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or
>   sometimes lose) reputation

Asking good question and providing good answer will raise your reputation.
When you have good question and/or good answer, share it with the community.

If you have the ability to ask good questions - do so 
If you have the ability to provide good answers - do so

- [Meta tips - how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Stackoverflow tips - how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Stackoverflow tips - how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sometimes we do fear that our questions may sound stupid (even after I've searched online for answers without success, same way like in real classrooms). So, i wonder if asking stupid questions give serious downvotes (which leads to loss of my hard earned points in future)!!

Comment: @vinaykumar2491 what most users forget is too include their research results in their questions. 99 out of 100 all we get is *I searched a lot*. sure, but we have no idea if you searched for Unicorns or Waffles, while should have searched for *fubar*. The next biggest mistake users make is not attempting anything relevant, at all before they ask their question.

Comment: @vinaykumar2491 - take a look at the "SO tips - how-to-ask" link in my answer